# Will Maa Kali forgive me?

Tags: sex

I promised Maa Kali that I won't watch porn. But I'm finding it hard to keep that promise. Please provide me with a solution as it is disturbing me a lot.

Comment: Mahabharat anushasan parva chapter 145"Those men who, impelled by desire in their hearts, cast their eyes on naked women, those men of wicked deeds take birth in this world to pass their whole lives in one continuous disease.".                         So whenever you want to do the wicked act remind yourself of serious disease you would be born with after committing act in next life. (You won't even feel any tempetation to watch porn if you set this in your mind)

Comment: My intention is not bad...I am a young adult who rarely used to watch porn but because of this promise I am finding quite difficult to keep.